# ADF - Import a CSV file that has multiple Tables

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a CSV File that has multiple tables. Each table is unique and has column headers.

Table1
| Col1 | Col2 | col3 |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| x | x | x |
| y | y | y |

Table2
| X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | X5 | X6 |
| -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

Table3
| Y1 | Y2 |
| -- | -- |
| Zed | 1/1/1900 |
| Jon | 1/1/1991 |

Any help on how to parse these out would be helpful. The end product will be powerbi. I can use Azure Data Factory, Datalakes, and/or Power BI to make this work.

I can just manually cut and paste, but there will be over 100 a month.

Theses are Zoom Attendee reports.

Comment: Custom formats require custom code.  Either treat it all as one column and load to a table to split out there based on the number of commas in a row OR write some custom Python and call a Databricks or Synapse notebook to import.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adf **Dataflow**, that will create separate csv files to each table.

So, First create a data flow with source as your csv file, you will get data preview as below.

[image]

Next, add **Derived column** to create new column called `table_name` containing table names.
Use below expression to create it.

```
split({_col0_},'|')[1]
```

[image]

Then once again create **Derived column** for getting table values in one column called `values`.

**Expression**:

```
replace(replace({_col0_},  concat({table_name},  '|'),  ''),'| |','\n')
```

[image]

Next, add **Select** to select new column created.

[image]

Here, `_col0_` will be there remove it.

Now, write each row to new file with name as table names itself.
To write add sink activity and set below configurations.

In **sink**, give sink dataset with linked service of blob storage,

[image]

and **sink settings**  select these options

**File name option** : **Name file as column data**
**Column data** : **table_name**

[image]

Sink preview will be like this.

[image]

After successfully running the dataflow you will get files in storage account.

[image]

You can see the data in look up activity with dataset configuration as below.

[image]

Here, i am taking table 2.

**Column delimiter** - Pipe(|)
**Row delimiter** - \n
**Quote character** - No quote character
**Escape character** - No escape character

Output :
[image]